# How to overwrite all the channels in the server Discord.js

Tags: server, discord, discord.js, channel, overwrite

and thank you for trying to help me! I am making a discord bot using discord.js. I made a mute command which works perfect and i am very happy that it works perfect, but now discord give's me another problem. If i want to mute somebody i gave him a mute role. Now that's my problem i managed to overwrite the permissions for the channel where i type the mute command, but i need to manually overwrite the other channels in the server!

> I want to overwrite all channels on the server!

***So my code is:***

```
     message.channel.updateOverwrite(muterole, {
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true, 
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true,
            TALK: false})
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [`each()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=each) function to iterate (loop) through each channel in the current guild and perform the action(s), as utilised below:

```js
// iterate a function through every channel in a server
message.guild.channels.cache.each((channel) => { 
   channel.updateOverwrite(muterole, {
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true, 
            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
            READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: true,
            TALK: false});
});
```

Comment: I thought it was `forEach`.

Comment: By evaluating the following JavaScript code, it is apparent that `array.each` is not a function:
`const array = [ 1, 2 ];array.each((x) => console.log(x))`

Comment: You are correct, `Array.prototype.each()` is not a function. However, the `GuildChannelManager` property `cache` returns a `discord.js collection`, not an array.

Comment: To be clear, both functions do mostly the same thing, It's just that `each()` will return the collection, while `forEach()` returns undefined. It doesn't make a difference in this situation specifically, but I always find it better to use just in case.

Comment: Haha no worries